# Excel Service Not Work after Import an Exported Application

Tags: excel, export, import, service

my Excel service is not working.My Excels opening in my Client MSExcel but not open in Browser.its happen after after my application has problem and I have to Export and import again to work fine.after do that my excels never open in browser
for fix this problem i do this :
1- Reset IIS
2 - Remove and reCreate Excel Service
3 - Configure User Account
but not work for me

Answer (score 0):

My Problem solved by do this
1 - in IIS Manger go to site and select authentication icon and click on  ASP Impersonation and disable it.
2 - my Excel service service pool is stop.I start it.